# How to find out which url that files upload to and data send?

Tags: http

How to find out which url that files upload to and data send ? ( When that website use flash )
Example megaupload website , i want to know where file upload to and its data .

**EDIT**: Now, I used HTTPDebugger , i parse header and data very good .

Answer (score 0):

several ways.

for instance, you can use on windows the command

```
netstat -abn
```

which shows you the server to which your system is connected (and which apps connect to).

you can also use tools like wireshark to watch the traffic of your system.

as soon as you know the server to which you flash app connects to, you can use an http tunnel (can easily be written in any language or take some existing developer tools).

On windows, you can use your hosts file (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc) to redirect any server name to your own machine in order to redirect it to your tunnel...

I know, it's not the perfect answer, but it maybe helps you to get a start with google :-)